# wordpress - I cannot call bp_notifications_add_notification

Tags: php, wordpress, buddypress

I am new in wordpress development and I want to start to develop a personal plugin which will i use in my site. my site uses wordpress and buddypress. In buddypress, they have notifications, which is pretty good. but i want my plugin to also add notifications to buddypress as well, and will appear to members.

I have seen the documentation here:
[bp_notifications_add_notification()](https://codex.buddypress.org/developer/function-examples/bp_notifications_add_notification/)

so far my code is below. Please note that i have removed may parts of the plugin just to simplify it

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Test
Description: personal plugin for my site
Version:     1.0.0
*/

function sample_add_notification( $u_id ) {

    $args = array(
        'user_id' => $u_id
    );

    bp_notifications_add_notification( $args );
}

sample_add_notification( 2 ); //this line should write a new notification for user_id: 2

?>
```

but when ever I run it. it says:

**Fatal error**: Call to undefined function bp_notifications_add_notification() in **C:\xampp\htdocs\htbcph\wp-content\plugins\test\test-plugin.php** on line **14**

i think the problem is, i need to include the component first. but how will i do it?
please provide me links for good tutorials that will help me. Thanks

Comment: you should attach your function `sample_add_notification` with a defined hooks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should attach your function with **hook/action**

```
function sample_add_notification( $u_id ) {

    $args = array(
        'user_id' => $u_id
    );

    // Make sure the noticications has been activated
    if ( bp_is_active( 'notifications' ) ) {
        bp_notifications_add_notification( $args );
    }
}
add_action( 'bp_activity_sent_mention_email', 'sample_add_notification', 10, 1 );
```

Where `add_action` holds:

1. **bp_activity_sent_mention_email** is a predefined hook/action,
2. **sample_add_notification** your own defined function that will call with hook
3. **10** Priority
4. **1** Number of argument passed, you have passed only `$u_id` so it is 1

Comment: thanks man, so does it mean that i will not need to add any includes or requires .. i just need to learn about using hooks?

Comment: @jks yes you need to learn using hooks, creating custom hooks, filters etc. And also have to fimilier with predefined hooks.

Comment: @jks I didn't developed any plugin yet for buddypress, but did for wordpress, add-on plugins. There is not so much difference in between.